# Is it possible that two items based on the same template will not have the same fields?

Tags: templates, field

I think ideally it is not possible but got confused when reading Sitecore's 9.3 learning module where this scenario is marked as true.

I wanted to inform on this but before doing so thought of checking with experts in this group. Let me know if i am missing anything here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not possible** that two items based on the same template will not have the same fields. If you need this kind of items then you need to create two separate templates that can use a single base template with the common fields and specific fields on the template itself.

Comment: Agreed, I got confused when in the learning portal this scenario is marked as true. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is learning portal showing wrong answer?